# Hot Removed SATA drive mount remains

Tags: linux, mount, disk, sata

After removing a bay mounted SATA connected drive the kernel will most of the time remove the mount. However, sometimes the mount remains even though the disk has been removed. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I ended replied to the original OP, you can always force an unmount with a lazy unmount

```
umount -l <filesystem|partition>
```

Nevertheless the thing about lazy umount is that it ignores the pending buffers to be written to that drive.

I would recommend a script a sudo for the user or a group of users that run the app, that only allows to run a script to umount the drive, and that can be invoked by the app. Or even a key on the console programmed to to call a script. (if a physical server)

Comment: The question then becomes how can I detect whether a mount is a zombie or not so that I know which mount I need to force unmount on.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from the user taking out the rive, not having admin intervention. Transfer the work of the umount to the user, that is why I am talking about an option in the app.

Comment: The application is a business critical application. I still can't have the it failing/being confused due to end-user mistakes. I can of course add an unmount button, however the end-user could still just jank the drive (some users are idiots). I would need a drive bay with some form of software controlled physical lock that the unmount option controls. However, I have not found any such product on the market.

Comment: Alternatively maybe we should switch to a usb based drive solution. Though we haven't found any USB based drive bays as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

I would not remove the actual drive without unmounting manually the mount point previously.

There are not guarantees the cache will be flushed or even data corruption can ensue otherwise.

One thing is hot mounting something, like a USB disk or a drive, a whole different story is unmounting it.

Comment: The cache is always flushed prior to removing the disk so there are no problems with data corruption. However, due to end user behaviour it's not possible to guarantee proper unmounting. Everything works fine except that we get zombie mounts every now and then which confuses the application.

Comment: Who guarantees you that after running sync there are no more writes?

Comment: The application makes sure to call `sync` before the end-user removes the drive.

Comment: And then you trust the gods there are no more writes afterwards and wonder why often the mount remains there. I am being ironic.

Comment: Not sure if you are trying to be insulting or not... The application is the only one writing to the mount and once it's performed `sync` it does not write anything else.

Comment: Let's say the end user DOES remove the drive while it's being written to. Then corruption on the drive is their problem. However, the system still needs to work, i.e. zombie mounts should be removed.

Comment: No, I do not intend to insult anyone, it just makes little sense. I am saying it is natural that often you have problems if you yank a drive without unmounting it no matter how many times you (f)sync it. And fsync only guarantees one level of buffers are flushed. And if you are saying you do not care, then the original question you posted does not make sense.

Comment: The question is whether it is possible to avoid/get rid of zombie mounts when the end-user removes the drive, whether allowed or not. Syncing/Flushing and whether the data is corrupted or not is a secondary issue.

Comment: You can always do a lazy umount with -l; however keep in mind you have the "zombie" mounts because your procedure has some flaw. Regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm a person that just registered here for asking exactly the same question and ran in to this while looking for the appropriate categories...:)

It could be so that, since you're writing to a fuse filesystem, and fuse is "filesystem in userespace", there's actually a separate user process running as long as the mount exists. This is just a theory, but I suspect that if this process dies or perhaps hangs, the state of the mount might not be updated properly, even if the disk has been detached.

In any case, it would be easy to test if this behaviour is reproducible by sending `SIGKILL` to one of these processes.

Comment: Fuse was never mentioned, although it is possible. Fuse is slow compared to native methods and it is not the best of the ideas to use it in some production system. In fuse, the situation about the pending syncs are worse than I am saying. Most of the hw that you can do hot inserts (namely CPU and disks), are not intended to be taken at random without some housekeeping tasks. If you want normal users/app users to be somewhat independent, better create a sudo authorisation  for a script that unmounts the drive, and create a special menu on the app for some users.